Navigation title changes only once in the session when app language changes
When I change the language of the app, navigation title updates only one time. When I wanna change it one more time, it does not update.
This solution works but it has a side effect, which take the user to the first view of the app.
Here is my code:
struct SettingsView: View {
    @Environment(LanguageSettings.self) var languageSettings
    @AppStorage("isDarkMode") private var isDarkMode = false
    @AppStorage("selectedLanguage") private var selectedLanguage: Language = .turkish
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(content: {
                Form {
                    Section(header: Text("Appearance")) {
                        Toggle(isOn: $isDarkMode) {
                            Text("Dark Mode")
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Section(header: Text("Language")) {
                        Picker("Language", selection: $selectedLanguage) {
                            ForEach(Array(Language.allCases), id: \ .self) { language in
                                Text("\(flag(for: language.flagId)) " + language.languageString)
                            }
                        }
                        .onChange(of: selectedLanguage){ languageSettings.language = selectedLanguage }
                    }
                    
                    Section(header: Text("Share")) {
                        Button(action: shareApplication) {
                            HStack {
                                Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                                Text("Share Application")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Section(header: Text("Version")) {
                        Text("1.1.4")
                    }
                }
            })
            .navigationTitle("Settings")
        }
    }
}

[[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/gwjcJ4yI.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/JpulImA2.png)

Using NavigationStack instead of NavigationView solved the issue.
Edit: I still have issue. Issue does not happen on iOS 17.5 but on iOS 18.x

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
